# CKEditor display text with NextJS using useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, state, next.js

everybody,

I'm trying to implement CKEditor in my NextJS project.

But I have a problem, I can't display the text I write in another div.

I always get an error every time, I'm new to NextJS, so I'm having a hard time.

Here is the code of my component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

function Article() {

  const editorRef = useRef()
  const [editorLoader, setEditorLoaded] = useState(false)
  const {CKEditor, ClassicEditor} = editorRef.current || {}
  const [data, setData] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    editorRef.current = {
      CKEditor: require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'),
      ClassicEditor: require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic')
    }
    setEditorLoaded(true)
  }, [])


  function onEditorChange(evt) {
    setData(evt.editor.getData())
  }


  return editorLoader ? (
    <div>
      <p style={{display: 'block'}}>{data}</p>
      <CKEditor
        editor={ClassicEditor}
        data={data}
        onChange={onEditorChange}
      />
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>Chargement...</div>
  )
}

export default Article
```

and the error I get every time I try to change the text :

```
CKEditorError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined

onEditorChange [as onChange]
./components/news/Article.js:20
  17 | 
  18 | 
  19 | function onEditorChange(evt) {
> 20 |   setData(evt.editor.getData())
     | ^  21 | }
  22 | 
  23 |
```

Comment: Could you `console.log` `evt`. I guess the `editor` is not in the `evt`.

Comment: indeed, it's strange because that's the way it's used in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor component receiving in *onChange* property a function that has 2 argumets – *event* and *editor*:

```
<CKEditor
    ...
    onChange={(event, editor) => ...}
```

So, you can write your onEditorChange function for example:

```
function onEditorChange(event, editor) {
  setData(editor.getData())
}
```

[Official Docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html) by CKEditor